# Set up date format during creating table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, datetime-format, create-table

I create column as below:

```
ReportingPeriod DATETIME
```

Now I noticed that it has format:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fff]    
2016-03-11 00:00:00.000
```

It's possible to **set up format as "DD/MM/YYYY" during creating table?**
something as:

```
ReportingPeriod DATETIME format("DD/MM/YYYY")
```

Comment: A datetime has no format. Don't mix up the value of a datetime with a formatted datetime which is always a string. Do not store datetimes as string/varchar. Convert them when you want to display them.

Comment: Are u using sql server

Comment: thank you for the advice Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
ReportingPeriod DATETIME CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ReportingPeriod , 103)
```

But as suggested by Tim Schmelter in comments, Don't mix up the value of a datetime with a formatted datetime which is always a string.  Convert them when you want to display them.

Means

```
`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ReportingPeriod , 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]` From *yourTable*
```

Sample Output

> 19/02/1972

Comment: Yep! that will be better!